# Reading alphanumeric data from text file

Tags: c#

I am using the code below to read binary data from text file and divide it into small chunks. I want to do the same with a text file with alphanumeric data which is obviously not working with the binary reader. Which reader would be best to achieve that stream,string or text and how to implement that in the following code?

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> ReadByChunk(int chunkSize)
            {
                IEnumerable<byte> result;
                int startingByte = 0;
                do
                {
                    result = ReadBytes(startingByte, chunkSize);
                    startingByte += chunkSize;
                    yield return result;
                } while (result.Any());
            }

            public static IEnumerable<byte> ReadBytes(int startingByte, int byteToRead)
            {
                byte[] result;
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    int bytesToRead = Math.Max(Math.Min(byteToRead, (int)reader.BaseStream.Length - startingByte), 0);
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(startingByte, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    result = reader.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: Is the file you got to read fixed, or could you change the writing to something like "CSV file with Base64 Encoded binary" or "XML file"?

Comment: @Christopher - it is fixed....can't be changed

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  If you read 100 bytes and then you chunk size is 40 bytes what do you do with the remaining 60 bytes?

Comment: @jdweng - i am reading it in chunks....continuing your example....40 bytes will be read first, followed by next 40 bytes,followed by next 20

Comment: One problem you will find is that reading a text file in any encoding that can handle characters that are larger than 8 bits (which includes all Unicode encodings) as chunked bytes will eventually result in you reading partial characters. You really want to read a text file as text, not bytes

Comment: @Flydog57 - Can you please help me with that

Comment: The easiest way to _"chunk"_ up a text file is to read it line by line and have your (non-equal-size) chinks match your lines

Comment: Line have NOTHING to do with issue especially if you are reading binary.  You have to be able to handle two conditions 1) Read until you get all the data.  So you have to make sure you continue looping and not return after one loop.  2) Append data to a buffer and then extract chunks from the buffer when they are equal or exceed the chunk size.

Answer (score 2):

I can only help you get the general process figured out:

String/Text is the 2nd worst data format to read, write or process. It should be reserved for output towards and input from the user exclusively. It has some serious issues as a storage and retreival format.

If you have to transmit, store or retreive something as text, make sure you use a fixed [Encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and Culture Format (usually invariant) at all endpoints. You do not want to run into issues with those two.

The worst data fromat is raw binary. But there is a special 0th place for raw binary that you have to interpret into text, to then further process. To quote the most importnt parts of what I linked on encodings:

> It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses. [...]
>   If you have a string, in memory, in a file, or in an email message, you have to know what encoding it is in or you cannot interpret it or display it to users correctly.
>
> Almost every stupid “my website looks like gibberish” or “she can’t read my emails when I use accents” problem comes down to one naive programmer who didn’t understand the simple fact that if you don’t tell me whether a particular string is encoded using UTF-8 or ASCII or ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1) or Windows 1252 (Western European), you simply cannot display it correctly or even figure out where it ends. There are over a hundred encodings and above code point 127, all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it is too complicated for me to understand as I fairly new in the world of C#. Can you modify the code to do what you are talking about?

Comment: @dude I can not modify the code to work, becuase *I do not know the encoding the string is in*. Without knowing the encoding for a string, **you can not process it**. Ideally I would need sample input, but with binary that has to be decoded into strings that is near impossible.